# Create Table with "SELECT AS" with additional new columns

Tags: mysql

I wanted to create a table based on another table, but also add new columns at the same time. I tried doing it this way:

```
CREATE TABLE est_temp AS SELECT establishment_id, uc_l_p INT DEFAULT 0, uc_l_t_p INT DEFAULT 0 FROM establishment;
```

however I get an error near the new values, uc_l_p and uc_l_t_p. Is there any way of doing this without creating the table and then ALTERing it to add new columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
CREATE TABLE est_temp AS 
  SELECT establishment_id, 
         0 as uc_l_p, 
         0 as uc_l_t_p 
  FROM establishment
```